# Pyinstaller 4.0 problem: Why I can't open it?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am new to python  and I want to make an executalbe python file  by using Pyinstaller 4.0 .When I try to run the .exe file ,it's not oppening. Do you have any idea why does it happen? I currently use Python 3.7.9

Comment: You need to make sure that any files that you used to create the executable file are in the same path as the executable file itself. This includes any photos, sound files, etc.

Comment: If you try to run it from the command line, is anything printed (an exception or such)? We generally require questions about debugging to include a [mre] -- the _shortest possible_ code that lets someone else see the same problem. Of course, that also means there need to be enough details to know if something _is_ the same problem, or a different problem that manifests the same way.

Comment: @Arty, it's quite possible to have pyinstaller bundle data files into your archive. Sure, we don't know that the OP is doing that, but we don't know that their program _requires_ data files in the first place; there's nothing remotely like enough information to allow a definitive answer here.

Comment: Thank you  very  much, guys .I found the solution of  my porblem ,thanks to your comments !